# Setting up Apache portable VirtualDocumentRoot under Windows 10

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp, virtual-host

I have the following code in `XAMPP`'s `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<Directory "/dev/www/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      # Require all granted
      Require local
      Require ip 192.168.35
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/dev/xampp/htdocs"
       ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAlias *.192.168.35.2.xip.io
       VirtualDocumentRoot "d:/dev/www/vhosts/%-7"
                          # ^ this works!
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine. Please notice the `DocumentRoot` in the first virtualhost lacking the drive letter and the `VirtualDocumentRoot` having one the in second.

If I try to remove the drive letter from the second virtualhost, apache fails to start. Like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAlias *.192.168.35.2.xip.io
       VirtualDocumentRoot "/dev/www/vhosts/%-7"
                          # ^ this doesn't work!
</VirtualHost>
```

Any way to use the path without a drive letter with `VirtualDocumentRoot` just like it works for the regular `DocumentRoot`? Even better, are relative paths possible, and, if so, what would those be relative to? This is so `XAMPP` is truely portable, as in able to be used on a USB stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of Apache explicitly emit the message `format string must be an absolute path, or 'none'` when failing to start. So it can likely be inferred that paths like `/dev/www/vhosts/%-7` (i.e. paths without a drive letter) can't be used with `VirtualDocumentRoot` on Windows (as `c:\`, `d:\` etc. are the root of a disk, not `/`).

Assuming that e.g. `/dev/xampp/htdocs` is probably your `DocumentRoot` in `httpd.conf`, you might (hypothetically speaking) be able to update this to something like `/` to allow Apache to be used from a USB drive but I do not believe this would solve the issues with `VirtualDocumentRoot`.